# sapui5 QUnit testing - how to use controller functions in my testcontroller

Tags: model-view-controller, sapui5, qunit

I am really new to the sapui5 language. And currently I'm starting with Qunit testing. My question is, how can I Import functions from other controlls to my test- controlls? e.g. in python there is an "Import function from module".

[this is my test for my configuration.controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsg42.png)

[this is my _getParentPath function in my configuration.controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFjG6.png)

the thing which isnt working is :

```
var sState = ConfigurationController._getParentPath(oObj.path);
```

the test is working I just struggle with that line, because I don't understand how to call my own functions from other controlls.

Comment: Qunit is used for unit testing in SAPUI5. When you say "controlls" - I am assuming you mean you want to test functions from different controllers inside a test case. There is a very helpful example of qunit doing this in the SAPUI5 documentation available here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/e1ce1de315994a02bf162f4b3b5a9f09. In any case, look at the documentation for jquery.sap.require for importing code: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/jQuery.sap/methods/jQuery.sap.require